# jQuery cropper doesn't work on dynamically generated image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have just downloaded [this jQuery plugin](http://www.jqueryrain.com/) that helps in cropping an image. I have the following function which is called on an `file` input field's `change` event:

```
function loadPreview(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $(".photoBox div").hide();
            var cropBox = $(".photoPreview").show();
            var $img = $(document.createElement('img'));
            $img.attr("src", e.target.result);
            cropBox.append($img);

            $(".photoPreview img").cropper({
                aspectRatio: 1,
                dashed: false,
                zoomable: false,
                rotatable: false
            });
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

The cropper code doesn't show up in Mozilla, but in Opera it does. Where am I wrong?

Comment: `var $img = $(document.createElement('img'));` is a bit quirky. `var $img = $('<img/>');` would be more conventional, jQuery-wise, and could be the source of your issue.

Comment: If Roamer's suggestion doesn't work, a fiddle would make it easier to figure out.

Comment: I discovered what the problem is. I created another page, but this time, I had the `img` pointing to and URL, and it worked. So **cropper doesn't work on base-64-encoded images**

Comment: You also need to be careful with `e.target` here because `e` appears to be POJS, not a jQuery standardised `event`, and there may be a cross-browser issue. Try replacing `e.target.result` with `this.result`.

Comment: I have recreated my exact same test page on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ebgpwrge/2/) and it works. It's diving me crazy. Is there any way of showing more errors in the console? (Currently, the plugin doesn't show any error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use createObjectURL func instead of FileReader:

```
imageUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(input.files[0])
$img.attr("src", imageUrl);
```